# Localizing iPad applications

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization, ipad

I am creating an iPad application, and I have a `Localizable.strings` file, which is in English and Dutch:

#### English.lproj/Localizable.strings

```
"failed to copy file" = "Failed to copy file";
"failed to copy defaultFeeds.plist" = "Failed to copy defaultFeeds.plist form the application's bundle to the device's documents directory for this app. Please make sure the device has space available on the flash memory. Please push the home button, connect your device to iTunes and check how much space there is available. Remove things you don't need and try again. If the problem presists, please contact us. You can find our support page in the App Store in iTunes.";
```

#### Dutch.lproj/Localizable.strings

```
"failed to copy file" = "Bestand kopieëren mislukt";
"failed to copy defaultFeeds.plist" = "Het kopieëren van defaultFeeds.plist van de applicatiebundel naar de documenten map van het apperaat is mislukt. Ga alstublieft na of het apparaat ruimte heeft op het flash geheugen. Druk op de Home-knop, verbind het apparaat met iTunes en controleer hoeveel ruimte er beschikbaar is. Verwijder dingen die je niet nodig hebt en probeer het opnieuw. Als de problemen voortzetten, kunt u contact met ons opnemen. U kunt onze support-page vinden in de App Store in iTunes.";
```

When I comment out error checking, so I get the error for sure, I get the English version, although the iPhone Simulator's language is set to Dutch:

```
// Copy defaultFeeds if run for the first time
    //if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:FEEDS_PLIST_IN_CURRENT_APP_DIRECTORY_PATH]) {
        // if(!) is for handling errors
        //if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaultFeeds" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:FEEDS_PLIST_IN_CURRENT_APP_DIRECTORY_PATH error:nil]) {
            UIAlertView *copyFailedAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"failed to copy file", @"failed to copy file") message:NSLocalizedString(@"failed to copy defaultFeeds.plist", @"failed to copy defaultFeeds.plist") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [copyFailedAlertView show];
            [copyFailedAlertView release];
        //}
    //}
```

Also, the debugger says:

```
There is no HW layout for this input mode, defaulting to US
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the Localizable.strings file through the Xcode4 interface?

The 'old style' naming (English.lproj, Dutch.lproj) has been replaced by the standard format (en.lproj, nl.lproj). Select the 'Localizable.strings' file and on the right hand side helper UI:

[image: This is on the right-hand side, hit the + to choose a language]

See if that changes anything for you.